# SQL where clause dependant on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i think its easier to explain on an example. so here are my tables

```
Table A 
id | Name
1  | row1
2  | row2
3  | row3

Table B
id | A_id | date 
1  | 1    |  NULL
2  | 1    |  NULL
3  | 2    |  2016-04-01
4  | 2    |  2016-04-01
5  | 3    |  2016-04-01
6  | 3    |  NULL
```

What im trying to accomplish is for my select on table A will only return values if the rows on table B associated to Table A have a Null date, at least one.

```
Select * from Table_A Where (?)
```

Is this acomplishable? i would only get row1 and row3 back, can it be done?

Comment: not enough time had elapsed when i tried to. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE
        b.A_id = a.id
        AND b.date IS NULL
)
```

Comment: thx, work as a charm, my head was revolving over this, couldnt get it straight

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID_A
    FROM TableB
    WHERE date IS NULL
)
```

Subquery retrives IDs on null dates, what is in turn passed to the main query to have what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filtered OUTER JOIN:

```
select
    A.id,A.Name
from A
left join B on A.id = B.A_id
where B.date is null
group by
    A.id,A.Name
```

JOINs are what DBMS optimizers are designed to do most efficiently, so generally using a JOIN where possible is likely to give best performance.

Comment: @LuisSiquot: Thank you; is this better?

Comment: This is a better approach as compared to the chosen answer. You should always try to avoid nested select statements and in this case it's so unnecessary.